# Reverse the values of a list of variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df in which around 50 variables have with character values ranging from 1,2,3,4

```
var
1
2
3
4
```

How can I "bulk" change the values reversing them such that I get:

```
var
4
3
2
1
```

So 4 becomes 1, 3 becomes 2, etc... Kind of like applying the formula (var = 5-value) for each variable but for character values.

This as mentioned for a long list of variables (~50).

Comment: You can do `5 - as.numeric(df$var)` or are you just looking to reverse the value with `rev` ?

Comment: Issue is how to do it for a long number of variables

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(var1:var50, ~5 - as.numeric(.)))
```

OR in base R :

```
cols <- paste0('var', 1:50)
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) 5 - as.numeric(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just subtracting the `data.frame` from a value, as you indicate in your example, you should be able to just do this:

```
df[] <- 5 - data.matrix(df)
```

Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4)), 
                 var2 = as.character(c(10, 20, 30, 40)), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[] <- 5 - data.matrix(df)
str(df)
#  'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ var1: num  4 3 2 1
#  $ var2: num  -5 -15 -25 -35
```

---

If you're just reversing the row order, then something like this should work:

```
df[nrow(df):1, ]
#   var1 var2
# 4    4   40
# 3    3   30
# 2    2   20
# 1    1   10
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use tidyverse’s mutate_at() or mutate_all().

Comment: Issue is how to do it for a long number of variables